# Snapping with measurement

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, configurable-map-viewer

Snapping with measurement tool on all layers/single layer not working.

```
this.featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(this.Khasraurl,
     {
         mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
         // infoTemplate: infoTemplate,
         outFields: ["*"]
     });

var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([255, 0, 0]), 2), new dojo.Color([0, 0, 255, 0.20]));

this.featureLayer.setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(symbol));
this.map.addLayer(this.featureLayer);

var layerInfos = [{
    layer: this.featureLayer
}];

// alert(featureLayer);
//alert(JSON.stringify(featureLayer));
//dojo.keys.copyKey maps to CTRL on windows and Cmd on Mac., but has wrong code for Chrome on Mac

var snapManager = this.map.enableSnapping({

    alwaysSnap: false,
    snapKey: 'CTRL', // key string ==> keys['CTRL']
    tolerance: 15
});

snapManager.setLayerInfos(layerInfos);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require([...,
                   "esri/SnappingManager",
                    "dojo/domReady!"],
                function(
                        ....,
                        SnappingManager
                )
                {
                ...
```

is there SnappingManager class in your code